# case insensitive word boundaries with regExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

for some reason the `gi` modifier is behaving as case sensitive. Not sure what's going on, but maybe someone knows why this is. it works fine when the cases are the same. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptv5N/3/) will demonstrate my problem. Code below. Thanks.

javaScript:

```
var search_value = $('#search').val();
var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "gi");

  $('.searchable').each(function(){
   var newText =(this).html().replace(search_value, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + search_value + "</span>");
  $(this).html(newText);

});
```

HTML:

```
<input id = "search" value = "Red">
<div class = "searchable">this should be red</div>
<div class = "searchable">this should be Red</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct Code is**

```
    var search_value = $('#search').val();
    var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "gi");

    $('.searchable').each(function(){
        //  var newText =$(this).html().replace(search_value, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + search_value + "</span>");
        var newText =$(this).html().replace(search_regexp, function(matchRes) {
        return "<span class = 'highlight'>" + matchRes + "</span>";
        });

        $(this).html(newText);

    });
```

**output**

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptv5N/7/)

**Issues with your code:-**

**First**: `search_regexp` - You haven't used `search_regexp` anywhere in your code

**Your Code**

```
 var newText =$(this).html().replace(search_value, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + search_value + "</span>");
```

**Second**
You are using `search_value` to replace. It will make both `Red` and `red` to either `Red` or `red` after replace.

eg: if `search_value` is `Red` then your output will be

```
this should be Red
this should be Red
```

you should use matched result instead of `search_value`

**Third**: How to use **RegExp** with  **replace** function?

**Correct Method is**

```
var newText =$(this).html().replace(search_regexp, function(matchRes) {
    return "<span class = 'highlight'>" + matchRes + "</span>";
});
```

**Explanation**

```
replace(<RegEx>, handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't using your regex in the `replace` call, it's just using the `search_value`.  This JSBin shows your code working: http://jsbin.com/toquz/1/

Do you actually want to replace the matches with the value (changing lowercase instances to uppercase in this example)?  Using $.html() will also get you any markup within that element, so keep that in mind as well (in case there's a chance of having markup in the `.searchable` elements along with text.

Might be easier to do:

```
function highlight(term) {
  var search_regexp = new RegExp(term, "gi");

  $('.searchable').each(function(){
    if (search_regexp.test($(this).html())) {
      var highlighted = $(this).html().replace(search_regexp, function(m) {
        return '<span class="highlight">'+m+'</span>';
      });
      $(this).html(highlighted);  
    }
  });
}
```

Your original code in the JSBin is the `highlightReplace()` function.